# How to view the RuboCop manual on a single page

Tags: ruby, read-the-docs, rubocop

RuboCop has [changed](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/commit/d40e8a9f800b8cac7345a67fab32139a2687273f) from a single page README into a manual with multiple, smaller, pages, available on readthedocs.io. Is there any way to view it all in a single page? Viewing the [last un-refactored version](https://github.com/bbatsov/rubocop/blob/43944e27ea125ba50686e46a79ca26454eaab791/README.md) of the README on github will work for now, but will become obsolete over time.

Answer (score 1):

The only way you could view it as one document would be to clone the repository and concatenate the files within the `manual` directory. You could do this with a simple `cat` command:

`cat README.md manual/*.md > manual.md`

However, there's no way to do it from GitHub.